# Attributes are not passed on nested shortcode

Tags: shortcode

I build one shortcode that takes two attributes.

```
<?php
function myShortCode($atts, $content=null){

    // I tried putting this line at different places but to no avail
    $content = do_shortcode($content);

    // extract the attributes
    $a = shortcode_atts( array(
        'name' => 'name="??"',
        'message' => ''
    ), $atts );

    // ... Here's my HTML stuff
    $paddingStyle = ' style="margin-left: ' . ((int)$a['tabs']) * 10 . 'px;"';


$htmlText = '';
$htmlText = $htmlText . '<div class="droptext"><a><img class="showHideContents" src="/wordpress/wp-content/uploads/2017/11/Dropdown_close.gif" />' . $a['name'] . '</a>' . $a['message'] . '</div>';
$htmlText = $htmlText . '<div class="expandableContent"' .  $paddingStyle . '>' . $content . '</div>';

    return $htmlText;
}   
add_shortcode("MyShortCode", "myShortCode");
?>
```

In the page I am doing this:

```
[MyShortCode name="First"][MyShortCode name="Second"][/MyShortCode][/MyShortCode]
```

Problem is the inner shortcode attributes gives me "name=??" instead of "Second". What's the trick to get the "Second" from the inner shortcode.  Outer shortcode is giving name correctly as "First".

Comment: Can you include the actual shortcode that's not doing what you want. Your example isn't outputting the name anywhere.

Comment: @JacobPeattie I added the two lines after "// ... Here's my HTML stuff

Comment: You're not outputting `$content` anywhere. So the 2nd shortcode isn't showing at all. Where's the 2nd name supposed to appear?

Comment: @JacobPeattie I updated the code with my actual html. You can see I am using  `$content` in second div . If this is not what you are referring then whatever you are looking for is mostly like the mistake I am doing...

Comment: I tested your exact shortcode and both names displayed fine, but the 2nd closing tag was visible. This is because you can't nest a shortcode within itself. See this answer to a similar question: https://stackoverflow.com/a/13184165/2684861

Comment: Experienced the same with the code. `[MyShortCode name="First"][MyShortCode name="Second"][/MyShortCode]` worked for me, so the 2nd clsing tab was gone.